# Understanding Kcachegrind callgraph number output

Tags: c++, kcachegrind

Hi I am new to using this tool and I don't have much documentation on it other that what I was able to google a bit. I have a compiled c++ program that I am running callgrind on and I see the call graph but if I don't use relative %. What do the numbers mean? I will see 3 numbers in the calling function box and a meter that has some blue fill in it. Also, the arrow to the functions it calls has a number like 224 x  and then 3 numbers under it along with a meter and blue fill also. Trying to get some exact information on what the 3 numbers mean and what the numbers on the arrow mean. Sometimes you will get 36 217 x on an arrow and then 3 numbers underneath it. Sometimes you will just get 359 x with no prefix number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kcachegrind display can be confusing.

The "three numbers" you are seeing are actually one number separated into groups of three digits.  Imagine comma's or dots depending on your locale between the groups of digits.   The one number that results is the cost (a count of how many times your program was observed in the function.)

The box with a blue fill is a "percent meter" so that in addition to the absolute cost for a function you have a rough estimate of how much of the total cost was assigned to this function.

PS: I don't know what the trailing 'x' means.  Maybe someone else can help with that one!

Comment: The trailing x stand for "time(s)". so if it says 36 217 x, it means this call was made 36217 times.

Comment: Hello, did you figure this tool out? Is there a possible way to obtain call cost (where 'x' are displayed). Really appreciate it if you cud help me.

Comment: @mozcelikors: Read Mosab's comment.  My answer plus his comment  explains what the number(s) and the 'x' means.

Comment: Hmm yes I got it but I want to know the communication cost. Instruction size where the arrows are. Is it possible? I saw the earlier version images which also had that.